db.sqlite to postgresql conversion in a django project
Error : RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not translate host name "postgres.railway.internal" to address: No such host is known.
warnings.warn(
No changes detected
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'railway',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '*****************',
        'HOST': 'postgres.railway.internal',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}````  




Earlier the database support was made via db.sqlite by sql is not supportd by vercel for deployment so had to convert it to postgresql but this error is showing up  

I do not have command over postgresql so i do not have it installed rather I have used railway.app for the purpose


What happens is you do a "ping postgres.railway.internal" from the command line?

well .internal is not a valid TLD, you need to update the /etc/hosts to refer to a valid IP  address.

Read Postgres database in particular section Connecting externally. Pay attention to Keep in mind that you will be billed for Network Egress when using the TCP Proxy..
